# How to jump to anchor BEFORE page loads completely?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, pageload, preloader

I have a very long page, with ~900 images in the grid view. Images are divided into categories, each category has an anchor. Right now, when I type:

www.domain.com/grid#1234

the link opens, but shows the top of the page, and then, after few seconds (time needed for page to load completely), it goes to the anchor #1234. I'd like to eliminate that time and go DIRECT to anchor location, before page loads completely.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 900 images is a lot, have you tried placing image placeholders instead and loading actual images after you have a layout?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, since the page loading won't pause to execute javascript unless there's a script tag after each image and isnerting 900 script tags to do the same thing is terrible design. What you could try though, is not load all 900 images directly, but just empty image tags and then load visible images After you jump to the correct anchor. But again, the reason why it takes so long is the amount of images. Look into techniques to decrease the load: placeholders, partials in lower res, lazy laoding only the visible ones, etc.

Comment: is possible, are you going to you se jquery? i can show you how

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. I think you'll need to run your javascript before `window.onload` or jQuery document ready. Try putting javascript to parse the hash fragment from the url, and then scrolling to that anchor. Ensure the javascript is below the anchor you want to scroll to, but not at the bottom so it doesn't have to wait for all that. If it still isn't working, you might need some sort of "while page isn't loaded, scroll to this anchor tag" logic. I would test in all browsers for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with jQuery, so i created a function with some properties to set, also it has the feature to stop auto scrolling by default and launch it if a hashtag exist in url, also you can it execute manually.

The code is:

```
function autoScroll(name,animated,distance){        
    var scrollDistance = distance;
    var scrollTarget = $("*[name='"+name+"']");

    if(animated){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: (scrollTarget.offset().top - scrollDistance)}, 500);
    }
    else{
        $('html, body').scrollTop(scrollTarget.offset().top - scrollDistance);
    }
}

//Stop default hashtag scrolling
window.scrollTo(0, 0);

//Execute stuff when entire page is loaded
$(window).bind("load", function() {

    //Check if there is a hashtag in URL
    if(window.location.hash) {
        //Get hashtag in URL
        var getHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        //Do the scroll function to the desired section
        autoScroll(getHash,true,0);
    }

    //Do it manually
    //autoScroll("second",true,0);

});
```

This is the example (i cant put a hashtag in url using jsfiddle, so i uncommented the `//Do it manually` to test.

https://jsfiddle.net/w7kchg4d/2/

Comment: You could use a bool instead of a string `"yes"`. Update your code to `move(getHash,true,0);` and `if(animated)`. May dont use the `name`-Attribute, you could use the `selector`. I updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DomeTune/svtq0c9j/3/).

Comment: i know can be improved (is an old code i have made for this), but thank you! i already edited. About the selector, you are right, but the guy here is asking about anchor tags (the old way) is why i keep it with the "name" attribute

Comment: Thank you TriForce. One question - where should I put this code? In the header section? at the bottom?

Comment: it doesnt matter too much, it will be executed in the same way, because you are giving "when" call the functions in the code (on window.load). anyways, any script should be placed at the end of the document because the pages will load faster